# css grid with nth-child

Tags: css, sass, grid

Is it possible to create a repeating pattern of uneven columns using nth-child? This is what I have, but it only works for the first row:

```
.three-cols > div:nth-child(1n) {
   width: 50%;
}
.three-cols > div:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 25%; 
}

.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n) {
  width: 25%; 
}

.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n) {
 margin-right: 0;
 }
```

So I want every row split:50%,25%,25%

http://codepen.io/garethj/pen/KNpQYd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three items per row so you need to use `3n` for each selector. You then offset this by 1, 2 or 3 depending on the element you wish to target:

```css
.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  width: 50%;
}
.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n+2) {
  width: 25%;
}
.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n+3) {
  width: 25%;
}
.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.block {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="block three-cols">

    <div>50%</div>
    <div>25%</div>
    <div>25%</div>

    <div>50%</div>
    <div>25%</div>
    <div>25%</div>

    <div>50%</div>
    <div>25%</div>
    <div>25%</div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
.block {  overflow: hidden; }
.block > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid purple;
  width: 25%;
}
.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n+1) { width: 50%; }
.three-cols > div:nth-child(3n+3) { margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
  <footer>
<div class="block three-cols">     
  <div>50%</div>
  <div>25%</div>
  <div>25%</div>   
  <div>50%</div>
  <div>25%</div>
  <div>25%</div>
  <div>50%</div>
  <div>25%</div>
  <div>25%</div>
</div>
  </footer>
```

Hope it will be useful.